# CheckboxControl does not visible change

Tags: block-editor, sidebar

I use the following code to add a custom option in the Gutenberg-sidebar. Its visible and saving the Checkbox-value works.

But: if I click on the CheckboxControl nothing visible changes on it. If it is not checked and I want to check it, it does not go checked. The "Update"-button goes active and I see the checked Checkbox after it.

Why?

```
import { CheckboxControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { dispatch, select } from '@wordpress/data';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { Component  } from '@wordpress/element';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        const meta = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' );
        const toggleState = meta['code'];

        return (
            <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
                name="code"
                title={ __( 'Display Settings', 'myplugin' ) }
            >
                <CheckboxControl
                    checked={ toggleState }
                    help={ __( 'My help.', 'myplugin' ) }
                    label={ __( 'My Label', 'myplugin' ) }
                    onChange={ ( value ) => {
                        dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( {
                            meta: {
                                'code': value,
                            },
                        } );
                    } }
                />
            </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found:**

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { useSelect, useDispatch } = wp.data;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
const { CheckboxControl, PanelRow } = wp.components;

const Sidebar = () => {
    const { postMeta } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
        return {
            postMeta: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' ),
        };
    } );
    const { editPost } = useDispatch( 'core/editor', [ postMeta.code ] );

    return(
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel title={ __( 'Display Settings', 'myplugin') }>
            <PanelRow>
                <CheckboxControl
                    label={ __( 'My Label', 'myplugin' ) }
                    checked={ postMeta.code }
                    onChange={ ( value ) => editPost( { meta: { code: value } } ) }
                />
            </PanelRow>
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because React is unaware that anything changed, all the props are the same, and so is the state, so no updates are needed. This is because you used `select` and `dispatch` directly from the `@wordpress/data` package.

You shouldn't use `select` and `dispatch` directly, you're meant to use the `useSelect` and `useDispatch` hooks.

You'll also need to convert this to a function based component, you can't use hooks with class based components

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I managed to find a solution and edited it above.

Comment: @ThomasZwirner can you post your solution as a solution rather than an edit? The site doesn't know that you found your answer if you edit it into the question